# Removing text after symbol

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to shorten event times on a web page to only show the start time, not the start and end time. For example, if the time says:

> 4:30pm - 6:00pm

I want to shorten it to just:

> 4:30pm

The time will appear several times on the page, and sometimes it will just have the first time, like I want. I have wrapped the time in a span called `.timeSpan`.

I have done some research on this site, and I found some similar examples, and tried to customize them for my purposes. I've arrived at this:

```
$('.timeSpan').each(function() {
    var s = $(".timeSpan").text();
    var n = s.indexOf(' -');
    var p = s.substring(0, n != -1 ? n : s.length);
    $(this).text(text.replace(s, p)); 
})
```

This does not work, however. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You are missing a period from the beginning of your initial selector.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.split()` is what you need.

```
$('.timeSpan').each(function() {
    var string = $(this).text();
    var times = string.split(" - ");
    $(this).text(times[0]); 
});
```

The advantage of split is that you get an array with all elements, means times[0] is the first one (start), times[1] is the next one, here the last one (end) - maybe you need it somehow else.

**EDIT**

The only reason why your code didn't work is because of this line:

```
var s = $(".timeSpan").text();
```

and

```
$(this).text(text.replace(s, p));
```

The first one is wrong because you dont want the content of timespan but this(within the for each). The second line is just repeated unnecessarily see this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/jy13fde6/

Comment: Just so I can learn, going back to my original example, was that at all close to working? I got the .substring part working in a JS Fiddle example, and I could show a popup of the text before the hyphen, but the text.replace did not work.

Comment: i edit my answer to show you how it workes with your code